# Problems with my script which doesnt show on chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

im having problem, somehow my script `if (myStringOld == myString)` and `if (regex.test(myString))` doesn't work on chrome, i cant figure it out why. myString and myStringOld is the date (format 2015-06-05) Can someone explain me or help to fix it. Because all the type it types else alert.

```
            var myString = txtCellEditor.value;
            var myStringOld = oldvalue.value;
            if (myStringOld != myString) {
                if (regex.test(myString)) {
document.getElementById('cellValueEditorDiv').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById(cellId).style.border = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    alert("Bad date format. yyyy-mm-dd");
                }
            } else {
                alert("You haven't changed the date.");
            }
```

Comment: Try `.match()` instead of `.test()`. And if the error persists. Try `alert(regex.match(myString))` before the if-statement. To see what is happening.

Comment: but still, how to fix first if which is `if (myStringOld != myString)` it doesnt work too

Comment: What values are coming to them before the if-statement?

Comment: myString is 2015-06-02 and myStringOld is 2015-06-01. And chrome makes it to be else which is `alert("You haven't changed the date.");`

Comment: Can you simulate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/17172/ here it is

Comment: In the jsfiddle no matter which browser, everything works perfectly.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works perfectly in Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 m:

HTML

```
<div id="cellValueEditorDiv">
   <input id="txtCellEditor" value="2012-12-20" />
</div>
<button id="submit">Test it</button>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: white;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var oldvalue = "";
var regex = /^\d{4}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{2}$/;

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var myString = document.getElementById('txtCellEditor').value;
    var myStringOld = oldvalue;
    if (myStringOld != myString) {
        if (regex.test(myString)) {
            document.getElementById('cellValueEditorDiv').style.background = 'green';
            //document.getElementById(cellId).style.border = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('cellValueEditorDiv').style.background = 'red';
            alert("Blogas datos formatas arba blogai įvesta data. yyyy-mm-dd");
        }
        oldvalue = "";
    } else {
        alert("Nepakeitėte keičiamos datos.");
    }

});
});
```

Try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/1drygub7/3/

Comment: Ye ive just find out that  it havent worked because of - `var myString = txtCellEditor.value;` So i changed to `document.getElementById('txtCellEditor').value;` and it worked.